# Show page title in document set

Tags: master-page, document-set

I know I could do this with just changing the master page, but I am wondering, if there is a simpler soulution.

When the user navigates to a document set, the name of the document set is shown as the headline of the site.
I want to archive, that the **title of the page** appears there instead. The name of the document set does not matter at all.
Is there a way to replace this in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say "I want to archive" - do you mean you want to change the 'headline' to something else?

Comment: Yes. I want the headline to show the title of the page and NOT the document set name anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this easily with JavaScript. I just edited the docsite default homepage and added a script-webpart. With javascript I read the title of the page out of the DOM and added it in the title. Pretty easy solution, but works perfectly. :)